# How to output multiply divs with data from API

Tags: javascript, for-loop, fetch-api

I'm using an API and I'm absolutely clueless how to output three divs with data from three different objects. What's happening is that JS outputting only one div. I wonder how can I prevent JS from overriding?

```
  function reviews(id){
    fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}/reviews?api_key=9250b9e19854d9deaa571f4074bc38a3&language=en-US&page=1` ,{
        method: "GET",
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        output = '';
        for (i = 0; i <3; i++) {
            output = `
            <img src="https://cdn.business2community.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png" class="align-self-start mr-3">
            <div class="media-body>
            <h5 class="mt-0 review-title">A Review by ${data.results[i].author}</h5>
            <p class="review-author">${data.results[i].author}</p>
            <p class="review-paragraph">${data.results[i].content.substring(0,200)}... <a href="#" class="see-more">see more</a></p>
            </div>
            `  
        }
        document.querySelector('.reviews-container').innerHTML = output;
    })
    .catch(showAlert())
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are outputting html string in the DOM after the loop has executed. That will only output the last html string in the DOM.

You need to append the html, not overwrite it and add the html to DOM inside the loop

Use [Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) function

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ...
    document.querySelector('.reviews-container').insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", output); 
}
```

You could also use `+=` operator

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  ...
  document.querySelector('.reviews-container').innerHTML += output;
}
```

For performance reasons, you should move following statement

```
document.querySelector('.reviews-container')
```

out of the loop body and save it in some variable.

```
const el = document.querySelector('.reviews-container');

for (i = 0; i <3; i++) {
     ...
     el.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", output); 
}
```

You could also concatenate the HTML string with `output` variable and then set the `innerHTML` of the element after the loop has executed.

This is better than accessing `DOM` in the loop.

```
 for (i = 0; i <3; i++) {
      output += `...`  
 }
  
 document.querySelector('.reviews-container').innerHTML = output;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have completely forgotten about += operator! Although, (for those who'd look into this topic in the future) it worked only when I replace = with += operator inside a loop. Any ideas why?
Also, for future references, If I want to write more "dynamic" code and display as many divs as there are objects, how can I achieve it?

Comment: if you read my answer carefully, i didn't add `+=` with `output` variable. I moved the `.innerHTML = output;` statement inside the loop. You could either use `insertAdjacentHTML` function or you could do `.innerHTML += output;` But if you use `+=` operator with `output` variable, that will work too.

Comment: Ahh right! Sorry about it and once again thanks so much for your post!